# Unable to download conda package (multiqc)

Tags: installation, version

Terminal shows the following when I try to install multiqc. Is it my linux version that is not compatible with the multiqc version?

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versionsThe following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:

  - feature:/linux-64::__glibc==2.35=0
  - python=3.10.9 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=11.2.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']

Your installed version is: 2.35
```

Tried the following:
conda install -c bioconda multiqc

Expected:
normal download of multiqc